# Executing a bad PDO query does not yield an error

Tags: mysql, pdo

Here is an invalid SQL and I m expecting an error, but the PDO error seems always 00000, what did I do wrong?

```
<?php
run('select now()');
run('pls give me an error');

function run($sql) {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;db=mydb', $user, $pass);
    echo $sql . "<br>";
    $sth = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute();
    $row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print_r($row);
    print_r($pdo->errorInfo());
}
```

And here is the result:

```
select now()
Array
(
    [now()] => 2017-10-03 02:58:09
)
Array
(
    [0] => 00000
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
)
pls give me an error
Array
(
    [0] => 00000
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
)
```

But I have another page running against the same db and get this error:

> Err 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
>       check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB 
>       server version for the right syntax to use near 
>       'please give me an error' at line 1

**updated**

The other page is able to produce error is actually using the following:

```
$sth = $pdo->query($sql);
print_r($pdo->errorInfo());
```

Answer (score 1):

For the syntactically or any other way incorrect prepared statements to throw you need to disable prepared statements emulation:

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

By default PDO is set up to emulate those, which honestly does not make much sense.

With emulated prepares disabled `PDO::prepare()` method creates a temporary server-side object that holds a prepared statement then executes it.

Additionally you may want to enable PDO exceptions, that way it's harder to not handle unexpected query failures:

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php

Comment: well, if doing as per your way: if there is error on prepare(), i need to catch error on execute() -- i never had this situation before, and imagin i m running 2 pages on same db, i imagine db settings are all same DEFAULT. why one page always no error ?

Comment: @SIDU I'm not sure I'm following your question. It's a PDO configuration, not database's one.

Comment: Thanks zerkms! Just wonder if some default PDO setting was changed last week?

Comment: Come on, you missed the question. The rant on the emulation is irrelevant here.

Comment: @SIDU if you changed something - something could have changed. If you did not change anything - nothing is supposed to change.

Answer (score 0):

I've no idea why errorInfo() sometimes doesn't work but I confirm he behavior.

Given that setting error mode to exceptions **always** works and given that exceptions are much more useful than manual error checking, this function is useless anyway.

So, change your function this way

```
function run($pdo, $sql, $params = null) {
    $sth = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute($params);
    return $stmt;
}

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;db=mydb', $user, $pass);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

run($pdo, 'select now()');
run($pdo, 'pls give me an error');
```

and have your error message first class

Comment: The "strange" behavior comes from the fact that `PDOStatement::fetch` does not adhere to the SQL-92 standard. The [note of terry](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php#62536) is the only place on web where I found this piece of info. It's in regard of the empty recordset, though. Note that it should be "_...and returns **FALSE** to the caller_". An important piece: "_This also prevents the exception mechanism from firing._".

Comment: Anyway this behavior is observable only in the case of `fetch()`, not in the other cases, like `fetchAll()`, `query()`, etc. I ran some tests on `fetch()` two weeks ago and, as I recall, in some test-cases, the error code remained indeed - unexpectedly - `00000`.